# What is the color selection used on Project>Options selected option

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, color-scheme

Right before I enter on SO, I detected that when I select an item on Project>Options dialog, it became dark blue with an black font (in other words, almost unreadable). Other items (not highlighted) are ok.

An example: when you enter in the Project>Options dialog the item highlighted is the "Conditional defines" on the Compiling Options notebook. In this case, it became unreadable. If I select another item, like "DCP Output Directory", THAT item become too dark and the other become readable. Here's an example where text below 'Conditional defines' is unreadable:
[image]

Because of that, I guessed that was an problem with the color scheme used by that dialog.

Looking on the "Environment Options" of the IDE, I didn't found an specific setting for Project>Options.

Anyone know where is configured the colors used by Project>Options... dialog?

Comment: Well, I for one cannot understand the question.

Comment: Not really. I don't understand what you mean by: "I changed something" and "when I click on something". What possible value does this question have for future visitors? It's not remotely clear what you have done, or how anyone else is going to match your experience with their own. You change something? Well, what did you change? Or, if you don't know what you changed, at least show us the impact it had. A screenshot illustrating whatever it is that happened. I've still no idea.

Comment: I'm trying to convey in a Q&A format the fact (which I didn't knew) that when I customize the Object Inspector colors, that selection it's also used to the notebooks of Project>Options in a not much intuitive way. So when I changed some color on OI - which worked ok - it make the selected itens on Project>Options dialog to became unreadable.

Comment: I've still got no idea what your question asks. A screenshot would help.

Comment: Easier: play with the Object Inspector colors and open Project>Options.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the onus is on you to ask a question that we can understand just by reading it here. That requires you to put in some time and effort. You did not do so in my view and are deserving of your downvote.

Comment: Ok, I'll transform that in a SuperUser.SE format.

Comment: It's ok now? I won't upload an screenshow because the firewall blocks imgur.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot understand. A screenshot would do it. I'd even edit the Q if I could see the screenshot. Anyway, I'm out of time now.

Comment: What it's your doubt? What is not clear?

Comment: None of it. I've no idea what you are asking. Never mind.

Comment: Seems Sertac not only understood, but complemented it!!

Comment: @Fabricio - Having the habit of working with non-default colors/metrics I hit this kind of thing every now and then. My actual situation was slightly better than the screen shot.

Comment: I cannot see the screenshot, @SertacAkyuz. But I can imagine :-)

Comment: The screenshot makes it clear. The words are still opaque but the screenshot means that we now understand.

Comment: Still opaque? If anyone follow the example with an XE2 IDE can imediately see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered while searching on Google (which doesn't gave any good clue) that the Object Inspector colors are also used by Project>Options notebooks. In particular, the highlight color is from 'Highlight Color' of OI and the text color is from 'Name' color of OI.

When I changed from the custom scheme to the default, all became ok...